# request.POST.get('sth') vs request.POST['sth'] - difference?

Tags: django

What is the difference between

```
request.POST.get('sth')
```

and

```
request.POST['sth']
```

Did not find the similar question, both work the same for me, suppose I can use them separately but maybe I am wrong, that is why I am asking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

`request.POST['sth']` will raise a `KeyError` exception if `'sth'` is not in `request.POST`.

`request.POST.get('sth')` will return `None` if `'sth'` is not in `request.POST`.

Additionally, `.get` allows you to provide an additional parameter of a default value which is returned if the key is not in the dictionary.  For example, `request.POST.get('sth', 'mydefaultvalue')`

This is the behavior of any python dictionary and is not specific to `request.POST`.

---

### These two snippets are functionally identical:

**First snippet:**

```
try:
    x = request.POST['sth']
except KeyError:
    x = None
```

**Second snippet:**

```
x = request.POST.get('sth')
```

---

### These two snippets are functionally identical:

**First snippet:**

```
try:
    x = request.POST['sth']
except KeyError:
    x = -1
```

**Second snippet:**

```
x = request.POST.get('sth', -1)
```

---

### These two snippets are functionally identical:

**First snippet:**

```
if 'sth' in request.POST:
    x = request.POST['sth']
else:
    x = -1
```

**Second snippet:**

```
x = request.POST.get('sth', -1)
```

Comment: +1. For mentioning that .get is default behavior for python dictionaries.

Comment: "This is the behavior of any python dictionary and is not specific to request.POST" I wish I had read this answer my first day with python... +1!

Comment: ¿ Where can I find request.POST.get() reference in DJANGO documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

**Request.POST Example**

```
req.POST['name_your_desired_field']
```

This will throw a KeyError exception if 'name_your_desired_field' is not in req.POST.

```
request.POST.get('name_your_desired_field')
```

This will return None if 'name_your_desired_field' is not in req.POST.

Although, .get allows you to provide an additional parameter of a default value which is returned if the key is not in the dictionary. For example,

```
req.POST.get('name_your_desired_field', 'your_default_value')
```

This is the behavior of any python dictionary and is not specific to req.POST

**Request.GET Example**

```
request.GET.get('name_your_desired_field')
```

This will return None if 'name_your_desired_field' is not in req.GET.

Allthough, .get allows you to provide an additional parameter of a default value which is returned if the key is not in the dictionary. For example,

```
req.GET.get('name_your_desired_field', 'your_default_value')
```

This is the behavior of any python dictionary and is not specific to req.GET

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between normal dictionaries access and accessing it with .get() is that

With
using something like
`request.POST['sth']` will arise a key error is if the ket 'sth' does not exist.
But using get() method dictionaries will also provide you with better error handling

```
request.POST.get('sth')
```

will return none is the key 'sth does not exist'
and also by giving the second parameter to get() will return with it as a default value.

```
data = request.POST.get('sth','my_default_value')
```

if 'sth' key does not exist the value in data will be `my_default_value`.
That's the advantage of using get() method over normal dictionaries access.

Comment: What is presented in this answer that is not already in the highly upvoted and accepted answer?