# Key Error when using request.POST.get

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get request.POST.get to work when a parameter is not provided. My understanding is that it [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518517/request-post-getsth-vs-request-poststh-difference) return `None` in such a case.  However, it's throwing the same error that I would have gotten had I used `request.POST['key']`: `MultiValueDictKeyError: "'key'"`.

Code:

```
def myRoute(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('key')
```

I've also tried using `try`/`except` with `request.POST['key']`, but I run into the same issue there. I suspect this may just be caused more by my unfamiliarity with Django and Python than anything, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm using Django 1.6.5/Python 2.7.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible. Django `QueryDict` objects, which `request.POST` should be, are subclasses of `django.util.MultiValueDict`, which implements `get` in the usual way. Are you sure that's the specific line that's throwing the exception? A full traceback might help.

Comment: I realized that I was seeing some really weird stuff in the traceback -- it always referenced the same two lines of code, regardless of whether or not they were commented out or even existed. Restarting the machine fixed it, so I have no idea what was going on. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could either provide a default value for the get method like so:

```
data = request.POST.get('key', None)
```

This will set data to None if no value is present. Or you could check for the value yourself:

```
if 'key' in request.POST:
    data = request.POST['key']
else:
    data = None
```

Comment: `get` always returns `None` if necessary if you don't provide a default value - specifying it changes nothing. Furthermore, the `get` implementation in `django.util.MultiValueDict` performs the `in` check as well - these two expressions both do the same thing as just `data = request.POST.get('key')`. The OP's problem is almost certainly elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure about this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict indicates that .get is just a .__getitem__ with a hook to add a default value as well. __getitem__ throws an error if the key is not set.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Check the source if you are not:https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/utils/datastructures.py#L337

Answer (score 0):

try writing it this way:

```
def myRoute(request):
    if request.POST:
        data = request.POST.get('key', 'SomeDefaultValue')
```

using the `.get` method shouldn't throw a key error; so if it still does, check your code as the issue is likely somewhere else.

Comment: `request.POST.get `should not throw an error  so how  it is used is irrelevant

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thats what i said... i've just suggest another way to ensure there is data in the POST object using the if statement.

Comment: yes but the point I am trying to make is you don't need another way, there is something else going on that the OP is not sharing as no matter what the `.get` method should not throw a keyError.