# Django user authentication not working/not logging in

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

I'm going through the Tango with Django tutorial and am trying to set up user authentication, however find I cannot successfully authenticate my users on the Homepage after they have been logged in (at least, I believe they are logged in).

My **user_login view** is

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Rango account is disabled.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'rango/user_login.html', {})
```

and in my **Homepage template** I have:

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Rango says... hello {{ user.username }}!</h1>
        {% else %}
        <h1>Rango says... hello world!</h1>
        {% endif %}
```

which should take me back to the Homepage and return 'Hello **USER NAME**' after a successful login, but it only returns to the Homepage and presents 'Hello World' and I don't know why.

Also, if it helps, this is the main part of my **user login template**, user_login.html:

```
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/login/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
        <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

My debugging suggests users are logging in, but the user information is not being passed to the home page, and in particular, the **user** variable is empty. However I am fairly new to Django and cannot figure out what is exactly going on to know for myself.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: are you using the `auth.contextprocessor` in your settings?does `request.user` work in the template?

Comment: Can you post your settings, specifically middleware and context processors?

Comment: And please post the code of your home page view. Are you sure you're using `render` there?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Roseman's comment about my home page index and in particular, **render**, solved the issue.

I was using

```
return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

to render the page, however after I swapped it for

```
return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

the problem was resolved.

Thank you Daniel and everyone else who contributed!

Answer (score -1):

`print` the value of `username` and `password`, maybe they are `None` it's why he didn't work.

**Info:** when you use `request.POST['username']` if you don't have value it's will raise a KeyError exception. I advise to use :

```
username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')
```

With this you can't have error, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518517/request-post-getsth-vs-request-poststh-difference).

To get info by custom field and don't forget to add `name` AND `id` to you div/input.

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" id="username" />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" id="password" />
```

Comment: what's wrong with `[]` syntax? It just okay. The difference is only that `.get()` returns `None` if there is nothing

Comment: The difference it's explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518517/request-post-getsth-vs-request-poststh-difference), `POST['xxx']` don't work for me but `POST.get('xxx')` catch data or return `None`. So it's easyer to find problem, if you don't catch data login can't work. So the problem isn't login but catching data.