# addBooks() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to take data from user and save it to database by using django. Have tried to solve it. But I am not able to solve this problem and didn't find any working solution on internet.

I am getting this error:-
[image]

My views.py file is:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from home.models import addBooks


def index(request):
return render(request, "index.html")

def checkBooks(request):
    return render(request, "checkBooks.html")

def contactUs(request):
    return render(request, "contactUs.html")

 def addBooks(request):

    name = request.POST.get('name', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    bookName = request.POST.get('bookName', False)
    authorName = request.POST.get('authorName', False)
    desc = request.POST.get('desc', False)
    book = addBooks(name=name, email=email,bookName = bookName, authorName = authorName, desc = desc)
    book.save()

    return render(request, "addBooks.html")
```

And my models.py file is:-

```
from django.db import models

class addBooks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    authorName = models.CharField(max_length = 122)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

This is addBooks.html(Here I am getting the data from user by using from):-

```html
<form method="POST" action = "/addBooks">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class = "container">
        <h1 class = "text-center"> Add Books </h1>
        <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control">
    <div  class="form-text"></div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name = "email" class="form-control">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Book Name</label>
    <input type="text" name = "bookName" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-text"></div>
  </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Author Name</label>
    <input type="text" name = "authorName" class="form-control">
    <div  class="form-text"></div>
  </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Description Of The Book</label>
    <input type="text" name = "desc" class="form-control">
    <div  class="form-text"></div>
  </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the full error traceback:-
[image: Full error traceback]

Comment: Can you share the full error trace back

Comment: I have edited the question for "full error traceback".

Comment: @KapilSharma your model and view **both** are named `addBooks` so when you write `book = addBooks(name=name, ...)` you are actually calling your view. Note: Ideally class names should be in `PascalCase` not `camelCase` also they should not have verbs and model names should be singular so it should be `Book` instead of `addBooks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your function name it is the same as the model name.

**addBooks** is your model name also your function name.
both can't be the same

```
def addBooks_add(request):   #change function name

    name = request.POST.get('name', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    bookName = request.POST.get('bookName', False)
    authorName = request.POST.get('authorName', False)
    desc = request.POST.get('desc', False)
    book = addBooks(name=name, email=email,bookName = bookName, authorName = authorName, desc = desc)
    book.save()

    return render(request, "addBooks.html")
```

or try this

```
from home.models import addBooks as addBooksCreate 

def addBooks(request):

    name = request.POST.get('name', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    bookName = request.POST.get('bookName', False)
    authorName = request.POST.get('authorName', False)
    desc = request.POST.get('desc', False)
    book = addBooksCreate(name=name, email=email,bookName = bookName, authorName = authorName, desc = desc)
    book.save()
```

Comment: Changing the model name should be better by the way. Do check my comment which points out the various conventions the name `addBooks` breaks.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat please check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

In addBooks function, you are taking value of name in the wrong way You have to try this

```
name = request.POST['name']
```

And Do this for all input fields.

Comment: Getting 'MultiValueDictKeyError at /addBooks' after using this.

Comment: that is a correct way . check this for more info  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12518541/8401179